# How to display a thin image on UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

I have a program that takes an image and crops out everything except for a thin rectangle. The dimensions of the new image are something like 500x150. How do I get a UIImageView to display the entire image without scaling it?

```
func putOnImageView(image:UIImage) {
    let cgImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(oldImage.CGImage,CGRect(0,0,500,150)

    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage!, scale:0, orientation: oldImage.imageOrientation)

    imageView.frame = CGRect(0,0,50,50)

    imageView.image = image
}
```

Comment: 500 pixels wide it is too large for the width to fit without scaling. https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. It was really helpful.